# XCode iOS Changing Interface of Existing Project

Tags: ios, xcode

We were tasked with modifying an existing app such that it, amongst other things, has a new interface. Correspondingly we deleted old interface related resources (AppDelegate.h/m, ViewController.h/m, and the .xib view controller) within the group and replaced them with the interface we had built in a separate xcode project (replacements for all of the aforementioned files and a Main.storyboard file). We then adjusted the Deployment Info such that the Main Interface was set to "Main.storyboard," yet when we build the project for iOS simulator we are still somehow provided with the interface we were to modify originally. We are clueless as to why the old interface resources are being used instead and how that is even possible, given their deletion.

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Delete the app from simulator, make a clean build and run the app again. If that doesn't help you must've left the old parts of UI.

Comment: That did not help. Are there any other components to a UI apart from the files mentioned above? The main method really does nothing other than delegate to the AppDelegate.

Comment: The main (initial) storyboard name is specified at the app info-plist which name is set at the project settings, but you said you removed the old files so I doubt that'd be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but yeah since the file was replaced it now states "Main" as the value for that parameter, which should be correct. We think that it must be something stored within the .xcodeproj bundle, since everything else seems to be consistent with our own work.

Comment: While you can place files into the project folder, it doesn't sound right at all, and if you meant some kind of settings -that is also doubtful since without actual files to compile the settings can't do what you described. Anyway, you might want to check the target build phases (mainly "compile sources" and "copy bundle resources", see if there's something that needs to be removed and if so check how it is still hooked to your new UI). Another thing to do is to try a new simulator - change the device type or iOS version (keep at least one version that you have problems with for future tests).

Comment: Sadly "compile sources" and "copy bundle resources" look fine. I'll try downloading an iOS 8 simulator to see if that makes a difference. The new interface does use auto layout which is only supported by iOS 6+, whereas the old app only required iOS 5. The deployment target was set to 6.0 though, but perhaps the simulator does not take that into account. So I'll give that a shot.

Comment: You are supposed to be able to launch the apps that use auto layout against devices with lower iOS version as long as it is not lower than the app's deployment target, of course you'd have to detect this situation yourself and handle it appropriately. As for the old UI that still appears, sometimes a simple solution is the correct - make sure you don't have it copied to the new UI resources and being used instead of the replacement counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using product=>clean from xcode menu. 
Sometimes xcode caches precompiled .xib files for performance reasons.